# Error with import script in colaboratory

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

When I try to import a script that is in the same folder as the colaboratory
then I get an error:

```
 ImportErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-e7a4315427c8> in <module>()
----> 1 import translate

ImportError: No module named translate
```

The path and location of the file checked!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Colab doesn't automatically load any files from your Google Drive folder; you'll need to copy the files locally (eg with something like https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/io.ipynb#scrollTo=P3KX0Sm0E2sF and then saving to a file).